# How can I prevent Autoptimize from crashing my JavaScript inside of an article?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, autoptimize

I have some JavaScript in my WordPress article, and part of it is a print view of content. I realized this with a `document.write` command. With it, I can generate a new HTML Page.

The Autoptimize plugin places its own script tag within my content of the `document.write` command, probably because it recognizes the end-body-tag of my `document.write` command content as the end of the whole page. This results in a malfunction of my script, because the script gets closed before the last characters of my commands.

Simplified:

```
<script>document.write('<html><head></head><body>blabla{THIS is the place where Autoptimize jumps in}</body></html>')</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry,

I've just found the solution, I can use the `<!--noptimize-->` tags for this...